# Error: 40 ... Could not open a connection to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem ,An error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server 2008.

When connecting to SQL Server 2008, I am using windows authentication to connect server ,

Comment: Show us your **connection string**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you sql server accept remote connections

`Sql Server Instance`->`Properities`->`Connections`->`Allow remote connections`.....

Comment: That should be: SQL Server Instance->Properties->Connections->Allow remore connections.

Comment: where is this Sql Server Instance in SQL Server 2008 ??

Answer (score 2):

check your firewall (is it blocking SQL? By default SQL is on port 1433)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to check:

Make sure that the SQL Service is actually running.  You can do this from SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Make sure that TCP is enabled.

Check that your firewall isn't blocking port 1433.